# Snowflake Connection to Google Cloud Storage in Australia

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking into the Snowflake platform for a client to use as their DMP. We have been investigating our cloud storage solutions (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud) and we're interested in Google Cloud, however on your website, there doesn't appear to be an option to choose the "Region" of Australia/Oceania.

https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/

Can anyone confirm whether it is possible for us to use Google Cloud Storage and Snowflake in Aus?

Sorry for the probably very silly question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment Snowflake only supports GCP regions in North America and Europe: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-regions.html#asia-pacific-regions

So you can't run Snowflake on GCP out of Australia just yet, but you could connect through to an account running on this platform in another region - or make use of GCS resources (in Australia or elsewhere) with an account you are running Snowflake on with another cloud provider "down under".

Comment: Thanks so much. This is hugely helpful. It looks like if we're wedded to Snowflake, we'll need to use Azure or AWS. Alternatively if we prefer Google Cloud Storage - we'll need to find a DMP. Do you happen to have any opinion on what combination you feel has been most beneficial? Or are they are all only marginally different from one another?

Comment: As I understand it performance is basically the same across for the board for Snowflake running on either AWS or Azure so the choice is yours and depends on preference, other cloud tools/options you are using. But it's worth comparing the costs as well based on what you are looking at - a nice calculator here to help with this: https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage (Google's object storage system) definitely has the ability to store data in Australia (this is done when you create a Google Cloud Storage "Bucket". However if you want Australia and *only* Australia, you're limited to a single region of storage (which is low latency, but less data replication and therefore a possibility of lower data availability).

[image]

If you want the more replication options for higher availability, you'll need to rely the Multi-region option which allows you to store data in "Asia" generally, but leaves the choice of the specific locations to Google to decide.